# ​tabs and app visibility changes on migrating package from one org to other org

Tags: data-migration

I have  made managed package, when I migrate this package to the other org my app and tab are not visible as defaults. i have to enable the visibility by editing the user profiles, while in my package  my app have visibility for all the profile and tabs are also  set to 'default on' settings.
 I want to override the user custom app and tab setting when my package deployed to that org. Need help with this ...